# Django query: use F in range lookup

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have BigIntegerField "a" and DecimalField "b" in my app model and try to filter queryset.

The following queries work fine ("Q" is used because queryset is filtered dynamically by several methods):

```
qs.filter(Q(a__lte=F("b") + 1))
qs.filter(Q(a__gte=F("b")))
```

while the following raises "conversion from F to Decimal is not supported":

```
qs.filter(Q(a__range=(F("b"), F("b") + 1)))
```

Why it happens? How can I fix it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fix it unless you use a development branch of Django. However that's unadvised for production applications. It's scheduled to be included in Django 1.11 as per this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22288). I don't know if it'll be backported, but it's in the release changes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#models